# How do I dismiss subview in MPMoviePlayer?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.5, subview, addsubview, mpmovieplayer

I have a video that auto plays at launch. When the short clip is finished it shows a black screen. I would like to dismiss the subview to show an image or auto load another controller??

Below is my code:

```
 (void)viewDidLoad

 {

    {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"cover" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                       initWithContentURL:url];



    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 960);

    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];


    player = nil;

}
```

Thanks for any help..i'm a rookie at this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a lot of this a couple of weeks ago. Check out the notifications available. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Add something like this to viewDidLoad:

```
// Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_moviePlayer
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:_moviePlayer];
// Register this class as an observer instead
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];
```

Now you have a method where you can re-add the view, or a thumbnail, or whatever:

```
- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{   
    // Obtain the reason why the movie playback finished
    NSNumber *finishReason = [aNotification userInfo][MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];

    if ([finishReason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {

       [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    }
```

(This code was adapted on the fly from my project, may need thinking to adapt!)

The MPMoviePlayerController has a lot of notifications that get fired when the movie is playing, is paused, is stopped, is finished, etc. You can add your code to those methods to get very good control of your presentation.

In my case, it took about a day of research and hacking (and maybe another half day of cleanup and tuning), but I managed to get a very nice play/pause transparent button, with a "play icon" image overlay when paused or stopped, all loading or unloading based on the player state. It's a simple custom player control that does exactly what I want. Totally doable, just start with one player state, get what you want, and move onto the next state.